# Can a WPF Browser Application run unsafe code?

Tags: c#, wpf, unsafe

I am writing some software that plots out fractals, and lets the user explore them interactively.  I currently have my code in a windowed wpf app.  I would like get into a browser hosted wpf app, so that I could display them on my website.  The problem is that the code utilizes some "unsafe" code to do the rendering.  I am using BitmapData to access the image memory directly instead of using the GDI+ stuff, because it seems to be quite a bit faster.  Is there anyway to run unsafe code in a wpf browser app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, provided you setup the XBAP as a Full Trust Application.

For details on the process, see [How to run WPF -XBAP as Full Trust Application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx).

That being said, it's problematic.  You'll need to jump through a lot of hoops, so it will not necessarily work the way an XBAP normally works.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. [Check out this section of the SDK for more details on XBAP security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx#XBAP_Security_Considerations). XBAPs run in a sandbox which only enable access to a subset of the WPF API and BCL. Best you can do is make a ClickOnce app, but you would need to sign that with a certificate that people will trust.